# Create dynamic reactive-form with controls depending on childs

Tags: angular, forms, parent-child, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I want to make a dynamic form which I cannot create until I'm on runtime and I choose in the parent one option. Every child has different inputs and only one is required so I can't create the form in the parent component and I have to do it on the selected child.

I'm trying to create the form in the parent and pass it to the childs like the next example but in the childs I'm not receiving the form correctly.

What I'm doing wrong?

**Parent.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
 <div *ngFor="field of fields; let i as index">
  <select [value]="value">
   <option value="child1">type1</option>
   <option value="child2">type2</option>
   <option value="child3">type3</option>
  </select>
  <div [ngSwitch]="value">
   <child-one *ngSwitchCase="'child1'" [index]="i" [myForm]="myForm"></child-one>
   <child-two *ngSwitchCase="'child2'" [index]="i" [index]="i" [myForm]="myForm"></child-two>
   <child-three *ngSwitchCase="'child3'" [index]="i" [index]="i" [myForm]="myForm"></child-three>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

**Parent.ts**

```
~~~~~~~~~~~
this.myForm = fb.group({
  fields[0]: fb.group({}),
  fields[1]: fb.group({}),
  fields[n]: fb.group({}),
});
~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**child1.html**

```
 <form [formGroup]="i">
  <input type="checkbox"  [formName]="child1foo1"></input>
  <input type="checkbox" [formName]="child1foo2"></input>
 </form>
```

**child1.ts**

```
~~~~~~~~~~~
@Input() myForm: FormGroup;
@Input() index: number;

this.myForm.fields(index).group(
.... the inputs of this child...);
~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**child2.html**

```
 <form [formGroup]="i">
  <input type="text" [formName]="child2foo1"></input>
  <input type="text" [formName]="child2foo2"></input>
  <input type="number" [formName]="child2foo3"></input>
 </form>
```

**child2.ts**

```
~~~~~~~~~~~
@Input() myForm: FormGroup;
@Input() index: number;

this.myForm.fields(index).group(
.... the inputs of this child...);
~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**child3.html**

```
 <form [formGroup]="i">
  <input type="number" [formName]="child3foo1">></input>
  <input type="number" [formName]="child3foo2">></input>
 </form>
```

**child3.ts**

```
~~~~~~~~~~~
@Input() myForm: FormGroup;
@Input() index: number;

this.myForm.fields(index).group(
.... the inputs of this child...);
~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: what is the error are you having? can you added to the question?

Comment: @Ricardo ERROR TypeError: control.setParent is not a function **(parent)**

ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in. **(child)**

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
**(child)**

But myForm is not null at the moment the pass it to the child, i don't understand